# "storage" should probably be a synonym for "internal-storage"

Tags: support, synonym-request

It seems to me most of the questions using [storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) would be better using [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage). Those that don't usually talking about the [sd-card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd-card).

Can anyone see why the two shouldn't be synonymed?

Comment: That seems logical to me. I'm wondering now how we should tag things about devices that don't have a physical SD card slot (GNex, for example), though. `sd-card` seems a bit confusing, but `internal-storage` could also be a little weird if talking about USB file transfers (though, really, it *is* internal storage I suppose).

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree as the trend is that external SD-Card is being dropped, Sony, HTC, Samsung... list goes on, maybe we are witnessing the end-of-days for those micro-sd readers embedded on a smartphone due to the production costs and that NAND storage is more cheaper to integrate.